# Count Data On Database

Tags: c#, database

hi i have table Answer in my access database
i wanna count it, how many answer available in every question

i try this following code

```
string sqlAnswerAvailable = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS CountValue FROM Answers WHRE Question_ID 
                              = " +myRun.questionId;
int count = 0;
Global.dbCon.Open();
Global.reader = Global.riyeder(sqlAnswerAvailable);
if (Global.reader.HasRows) {
   while (Global.reader.Read()) {
       count = Global.reader.GetInt32(0);
   }
}
Global.dbCon.Close();
```

but i get `Syntax error in FROM clause'...`

where i'm missing? Or how correct way to do it?

Comment: `WHERE` instead of `WHRE`?

Comment: Don't concatenate strings to perform queries.  Use parameters and avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where i'm missing?

change `WHRE` to `WHERE` in your sql statement, that will solve your syntax error but you better Use sql parameters, you are open for SQL Injection Vulnerabilities.

If you need only the count you can use ExecuteScalar method

Answer (score 0):

Check Spelling mistake in **WHERE**

Try this

```
string  sqlAnswerAvailable = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS CountValue FROM Answers WHERE Question_ID 
                                  = " +myRun.questionId;
```